# "Sun rises in the east" or "The sun rises in the east"

Tags: articles, definite-articles, proper-nouns

I am really confused about the usage of articles with proper nouns like *sun.* Which of the following is correct?

1. Sun rises in the east.
2. ***The*** sun rises in the east.

Answer (score 0):

"**The** sun rises in the east." (note that a capital letter is also often used for "the Sun" since it can be considered a proper noun, though it is often not used)

Answer (score 0):

A unique thing that there is only one of its kind usually takes the definite article, such as the sun, the moon and the  universe. Therefore, your second example is the correct answer.

Comment: generally true, but if this was a company name (named Sun) and some writer decided to write "Sun rises in the east," (i.e. talking about Sun Company entering a new market) it would be grammatical. THis may confuse the OP further, but usage such as this may have contributed to the question.

Comment: @Yorik: You are right, but my answer was specific. I said UNIQUE THINGS and gave examples.

Comment: I get that, my only purpose was to help clarify a potential problem for the OP